# invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'bool')

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm pretty new to `C++` and am currently trying to learn pointers. Below is the code for my program and I'm getting the error:

> error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'bool')

I'm trying to set a new value to the `i index` of the array pointer. What am I doing wrong here?

```
int opendoors(int n, int r)
{
    bool * open = new bool[n];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        *open[i] = 1;
    }

    int incdoor = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            *open[i - incdoor] = 0;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            *open[i + incdoor] = 1;
        }

        incdoor++;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (*open[i] == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    delete [] open;

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int n, r;
    std::cin >> n >> r;
    std::cout << opendoors(n, r) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `*open[i] = 1;` to `open[i] = true;`

Comment: That's not the entire error message. It included at least a line number, and that's important information. In general, if you're lost, summarizing is a bad idea.

Comment: PS: Use `true` and `false` not 1 and 0 in C++

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for the help and tip!

Comment: Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). It's about C, but most or all of that section applies to C++ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `open[i]`. You can either use an array index or the dereference operator on a pointer, but not both.

Comment: Never knew that but that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Quiver If you think about the types, `open` is a `bool*`, so `open[i]` is just a `bool`. So `*open[i]` is attempting to use the `*` operator on an object of `bool` type. This is invalid usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your problem but it is something that you should be aware of. There is a bug in your code. Your function takes two integer arguments and your first parameter `n` you are using to create a dynamic array of Boolean variables. However; in both of your for loops where you are setting your range of the loop to do work on the dynamic array you are using the wrong comparison operator `<=`. This should be `<`. Can you guess why? When you begin to use an index into an array they are `0` based. So let's say you pass `3` into the first argument of your function; this will then create dynamic array of 3 Boolean variables. Now in your for loops you begin your index `i` at `0` which is correct but when it is compared to `<=` let's see what happens:

```
i = 0; // First Index
i = 1; // Second Index
i = 2; // Third Index
i = 3; // Fourth Index - Still a Valid pass of the for loop because the condition is true;
       // however, we have a memory problem because the index i is out of bounds as there 
       // are only 3 bools in the array and not 4.
```

Comment: Yeah I actually noticed this when I was reviewing my code after posting this question. I'm aware that it is out of bounds, just missed that I typed that when making my for loops. Thanks for pointing it out though :)